# Is there a way to write this small piece of code in a more elegant, optimized way? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to teach myself ES6 for a short while now. Here is a small example of stuff that I learned, like let, const and => functions. Is there a more elegant or shorter way to write this? Maybe replace for loop with forEach? Any tips and help are welcome.

```
'use strict';
const countChar = (string, ch) => {
    let counted = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) === ch) {
            counted += 1;
        }
    }
    return counted;
};

const countBs = string => countChar(string, 'B');

console.log(countBs('BBC'));
console.log(countChar('kakkerlak', 'k'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to shorten it

```js
'use strict';
const countChar = (string, ch) => string.split(ch).length - 1;
const countBs = string => countChar(string, 'B');

console.log(countBs('BBC'));
console.log(countChar('kakkerlak', 'k'));
```

Comment: This is indeed a lot shorter, the original was way longer than my version and yours is way shorter than mine. I like this, I also like the fact that I should never come up with something like this. If you were building something like this should you use your solution?

Comment: Sure, I'd have no problem using this in production code, in fact I use `split` in similar ways all the time

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

```js
alert('kakkerlak'.match(/k/g).length)
```

Comment: Crown teh winnar.

Comment: `string.match(new RegExp(ch,'g')).length`

Comment: This is extremely short xD I don't think anyone will get any shorter than this, but I never used regular expressions before, so this will not be the most friendly approach for me. But I will for sure look at Regular expressions for more information on this topic.

Comment: Actually, `string.split(ch).length-1` is 14 bytes shorter

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily related to ES6, but a more functional approach, e.g. using `filter()` seems nice here:

```js
const countChar = (string, needle) =>
  string.split('')
    .filter(char => char === needle)
    .length;

const countBs = string => countChar(string, 'B');

console.log(countBs('BBC'));
console.log(countChar('kakkerlak', 'k'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegance is in the eye of the beholder but here's a way to reduce it further by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
'use strict';

const countChar = (string, ch) => 
  string.split('').reduce((sum, c) => sum + (c === ch), 0);

const countBs = string => countChar(string, 'B');

console.log(countBs('BBC'));
console.log(countChar('kakkerlak', 'k'));
```

It works by converting the string into an array of characters then summing up the number of characters in that array which match `ch`. I also (ab)use the fact that `true` converts to `1` and `false` converts to `0` so adding `c === ch` to the running sum will add `1` if it matches and `0` if it doesn't.

Comment: I think that instead of abusing the fact that `true` converts to `1` and `false` converts to `0`, you should do something like that: `(c === ch ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: @Gothdo You could. I prefer the abuse in this case since I was just trying to make it more compact. To me, it also reads quite well. "Add another if the characters match."